# Error while cross compiling poppler package

Tags: c, cross-platform, embedded-linux, building

I am getting the following error while cross compiling Poppler package on Ubuntu

After configuring I gave command make
then while making the following error has come

GlobalParams.cc:81:35: fatal error: fontconfig/fontconfig.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [libpoppler_la-GlobalParams.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/media/COMMON/WorkSpace/Packages/poppler-0.41.0/poppler'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory`/media/COMMON/WorkSpace/Packages/poppler-0.41.0/poppler'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/media/COMMON/WorkSpace/Packages/poppler-0.41.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2

I even check the includes which I had given while configuring it has the fontconfig/fontconfig.h but den still the error is coming.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should cross-compile the fontconfig library,then include the headers and libs into Popper.
Download the latest fontconfig and excute the conmmand below:
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/poppLib/lib/pkgconfig ./configureCC=arm-linux-gcc --host=arm-linux --build=i386-linux --prefix=/opt/poppLib--with-arch=arm --enable-libxml2 --disable-docs
    make &&  make install
then add the include and lib in your Popper ,try compile it again.

Comment: I cross compiled the latest FontConfig and also Freetype packages also included their repectives includes and libarraies..and den gave suitable paths ,but still the error appears

Comment: check whether the include way is <fontconfig/fontconfig.h> ,and change it to "../fontconfig/fontconfig.h".

Comment: I dont know in which file should I include the Path ./fontconfig/fontconfig.h ?

Comment: GlobalParams.cc:81:35: fatal error: fontconfig/fontconfig.h:

Comment: Thanks . Got thru the error but now I am facing with the following error                                                                                                         
/opt/TINY6410/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.5.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: warning: libfontconfig.so.1, needed by ../poppler/.libs/libpoppler.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
../poppler/.libs/libpoppler.so: undefined reference to `FcPatternDestroy'
../poppler/.libs/libpoppler.so: undefined reference to `FcPatternGetLangSet'     Still it error

Comment: Getting Error                                                                               make[2]: Leaving directory `/media/COMMON/WorkSpace/Packages/poppler-0.41.0/poppler'
Making all in utils
make[2]: Entering directory `/media/COMMON/WorkSpace/Packages/poppler-0.41.0/utils'
  CXXLD    pdfdetach
../poppler/.libs/libpoppler.so: undefined reference to `FcPatternDestroy'
../poppler/.libs/libpoppler.so: undefined reference to `FcPatternGetLangSet'